# Find the last digits of $a_{2009}$, and of $b_{2009}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic, decimal-expansion, tetration, power-towers

Define the sequences *$a_1, a_2,...$* and $*b_1, b_2,...*$ by $a_1 = b_1 = 7$ and 
$$a_{n+1} = {a_n}^7, \\ b_{n+1} = 7^{b_n}$$ for $n\ge 1$.

Find the last digits of $a_{2009}$, and of $b_{2009}$.
What about the last two digits or more?

I know the order of 7 mod 100 is 4. Im  not sure if that helps but how will we work this out?

Comment: For the $\{a_n\}$, say...have you written out the first few terms $\pmod {100}$?

Comment: In both cases $a_n,b_n$ are of the form $$7^{4m+3}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part 1:$$a_1\equiv(mod10)7 $$$$a_2=7^7\equiv(mod10)(-3)^7\equiv3$$$$a_3=a_2^7\equiv(mod10)3^7\equiv7$$$$.$$$$.$$$$.$$$$a_{2009}\equiv(mod10)7$$'''''''''''''''''''''$$a_1\equiv(mod100)7$$ by a simple calculation we have $7^4\equiv(mod100)1$
$$a_2\equiv(mod100)a_1^7\equiv7^7\equiv7^3$$
$$a_3\equiv(mod100)a_2^7\equiv(7^3)^7\equiv7^{21}\equiv7(7^4)^5\equiv7$$
$$a_4\equiv(mod100)7^3$$
$$$$
and then we have:
$$a_{2009}\equiv(mod100)7
$$''''''''''''''''''''''$$$$
Part 2:$$$$
We need to show $b_n\equiv(mod4)3$$$$$
Proof by induction:$$b_1\equiv(mod4)3$$
$$b_k\equiv(mod4)3 \Longrightarrow b_{k+1}\equiv(mod4)3$$$$b_{k+1}=7^{b_k}\equiv(mod4)(-1)^{4k+3}\equiv-1\equiv3$$$$$$now we have:$$b_n\equiv(mod100)7^{b_{n-1}}\equiv7^{4k+3}\equiv7^3\equiv43$$$$$$$$b_n\equiv(mod10)7^{4k+3}\equiv7^3\equiv3$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: We have

$$a_n=7~\widehat~~7~\widehat~~(n-1)$$

$$b_n=7~\widehat~~ b_{n-1}=7~\widehat~~7~\widehat~~b_{n-2}=\dots$$

and in the case of finding the last two digits, the order of $7$ mod $100$ is $4$ and the order of $7$ mod $4$ is $2$, so

$$a_n\equiv7~\widehat~~(7~\widehat~~[(n-1)\bmod2]\bmod4)\pmod{100}$$

$$b_n\equiv7~\widehat~~(7~\widehat~~[b_{n-2}\bmod2]\bmod4)\pmod{100}$$

and the same strategy can be applied to find more digits.